# IISExpress with trace flag gives no additional information and still prompts to run with trace flag

Tags: windows-10, iis-express, iis-express-10

I am trying to run IISExpress with no options just `iisexpress.exe`, and I am getting the following error

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).

I am *not* really concerned about the error message itself or the fact that IIS Express isn't running, but what I am concerned about is that I try running it again with the `/trace:error` flag and I get the same exact message.

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).

I would expect to get more information when running with the `/trace:error` flag, and I wouldn't expect it to continue prompting me to try again with the `trace:error` flag.

Am I missing something, or is this a known issue, and there just isn't any additional information about this particular error?

The product version of IISExpress.exe that I am using is 10.0.14358.1000

Comment: It's a known issue for years, and I don't think Microsoft is ever going to fix it.